# ScrollTop strange padding

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

Been working on a personal site lately and using jQuery ScrollTop to animate my content div. But I've ran into a problem.

- **1st:** there is a strange padding in the top of every  involved
- **2nd:** the scroll is not consistent, ie. it doesn't scroll the same height every time.

You can see the page here: http://mnpwr.dk/v2/index.html

*- I added a red border around, so it would be easier to see the problem.*

**The jQuery:**

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    getHash();
});

// Keep track of our current state
currentSection = 1;

function getHash() {

    jQuery('.scroll').on('click', function () {
        // Get our new state
        var gethash = jQuery(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0];
        // Calculate the difference, with element height of 500px using formular dest = (newPows - currentPos) * elmHeight
        var scrollTop = (gethash - currentSection) * 500
        jQuery('#contentDiv').animate({
            scrollTop: scrollTop
        }, 500);

        return false;

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add in CSS

```
p{
 margin:0px;
}
```

Hope this clarifies your 'problem'

Your next problem is that if you have elements which height is 500px, if you add a red border 1px than the element's height will actually be 502 :)
So if you animate 500 by 500, the position will not be precise.

Just a suggestion, use `.position()` to get an element position and animate `scrollTop` to that retrieved value

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/efizuc/4/edit)**

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed that. This only answers one of my questions though. It still seems as if the div's do not scroll the same length every time. They scroll a little less the further down the menu you go.

Comment: @Köd I explained about your 2nd issue in my answer.

Comment: Actually the margin fixed everything, the border was just to show the problem ;) Everything looks great now, thanks! Just wondering, how would you suggest using the .offset(), I might use it for another time.

Comment: @Köd lemme setup an example

Comment: @Köd http://jsbin.com/efizuc/4/edit take a look at the `ID` names change in HTML :) And BTW I had to use `.position()` instead of `.offset()` in this specific case. That example offers you to e.g. use min-height for your containers, but have the possibility to have more content than 500px inside a .content! :)